# Render an ExpansionTile's child across a row of ExpansionTiles

Tags: flutter

Given a row of ExpansionTile widgets, is it possible for them to share the space their children occupy?

In the example below, there are two ExpansionTiles on one row. When one is clicked, the child only renders in the width that its corresponding ExpansionTile occupies.

I'd like for any ExpansionTile in that row, when expanded, to occupy the entirety of the following row for its child. Clicking one would collapse the currently selected tile and expand the newly selected one.

I understand this may not be feasible with the current pre-build widgets, but I wanted to make sure nothing already existed to do this before building it from scratch.

[image: Two expansion tiles in one row]

Comment: I think it should work, but I never tried it. I would recommend to use a Row and I would put 2 expanded widgets and inside each one put the expansionTile widget.

Comment: That was my first solution and the one you see in the image above. The issue with that is the child widget is only as wide as the button, but I want it to be as wide as the row.